# AppFabric Installation Problem

Tags: installation, appfabric

Hoping someone else has already encountered this and has a solution...

I'm trying to install the AppFabric Beta 1 caching service, on a virtual Windows Server 2008 (CacheServer1). My cache configuration information will be held in a SQL Server database on a separate server (SQLServer). As AppFabric only supports Integrated Security for SQL Server, both servers are in the same domain, and I'm installing using an account that has db_owner rights to my VelocityConfig database.

When I run the AppFabric installer and get to entering the connection string for my SQL server, I put in the server name, but when I click the combo box to get the list of databases from the server, it thinks for a minute and then I get a timeout error.

Both servers can ping each other, and I've created a .UDL file on CacheServer1 under the same user, which can connect successfully to SQLServer and retrieve a list of databases.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get the installer to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to this was to install the SQL 2008 Client Connectivity bits on CacheServer1, once this was installed I could get a list of databases. Still can't get AppFabric to install successfully but that's another problem for another question I think...

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that there is no network/DNS issues, can you try the following:
1. Use IP address instead of hostname.
2. Are you able to connect to sql server via sql server mgmt studio running on CacheServer1?

Comment: I'm currently rebuilding my virtual server environment - once I've got a set of servers again I'll try these suggestions and update you.